# Удаление строк DataFrame, содержащих NaN в определенном столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

Необходимо удалить все строки DataFrame, где значение столбца `filename` равно NaN. 
Код:
`for n in range(len(df_common_fin)):
    if df_common_fin.iloc[n, 'filename'] == np.nan:
        df_common_fin.drop(index=n)`

не работает, хотя прохожу по порядковым индексам iloc. Выдается ошибка:

> ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types

такой код:

```
for n in range(len(df_common_fin)):
if df_common_fin['filename'][n] == np.nan:
    df_common_fin.drop(index=n,axis=0)
```

так же выдаешь ошибку:

> KeyError: 0

Comment: можете привести примеры входных фреймов? Выражение `со строками '1','2','3'` можно воспринять двояко... `'1','2','3'` - это значения индексов или значения одной строки?

Comment: Понятнее было бы если бы вы показали примеры входных и выходной дата сеты... [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Создайте в любом текстовом редакторе маленькие примеры входных данных  - это же не так сложно...

Comment: Изменил вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.dropna(subset=['colX','colY'])](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df_common_fin = df_common_fin.dropna(axis='index', how='any', subset=['filename'])
```

---

Ошибка в вашем коде вызвана тем что "accessor" `df.iloc[]` воспринимает только позиционные аргументы, как для индекса, так и для столбцов.

Т.е. `df_common_fin.iloc[n, 'filename']` надо переписать так:

```
df_common_fin.iloc[n, <numeric_index_of_filename_column>]
```

---

Следующая проблема, которая бы у вас возникла это: `np.nan != np.nan` - как следствие конструкция `if ...` всегда была бы ложной:

```
In [139]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[139]: False

In [140]: np.nan != np.nan
Out[140]: True
```

т.е. одна "неопределенность" не обязательно равна другой "неопределенности".

Поэтому в Pandas существуют [функции для работы с `NaN`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html):

- pd.isna, pd.isnull
- pd.nontna, pd.notnull
- DataFrame.isna, DataFrame.isnull
- DataFrame.notna, DataFrame.notnull
- DataFrame.dropna

Comment: Благодарю! Элегантно!